# Downlaod files from server if fails retry for 5 times in interval of 30s in Android

Tags: android, runnable, android-download-manager, android-handler, android-thread

I am receiving array of .apk files from server. This files have to be downloaded and installed in the phone. If meanwhile downloading fails due to any reseaons i want to retry downloading of file for 5 times in every 30 seconds inetrval. Also i have to make sure that there should be no simultaneous download to avoid overhead in server.

So i thought of using Handlers to retry but my code is downloading two-three files simultaneous;y while retrying.

```
try {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>26) {
            Log.d("downloading...", filename);
            URL url = new URL(ur);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDownload/";

            Path path = Paths.get(PATH);

            if(!Files.exists(path)){
                File dir = new File(PATH);
                if(dir.mkdir())
                    Log.d("is directory exists", "Directory creation success");
                else {
                    Log.d("is directory exists", "Directory creation Failed");
                    return;
                }
            }






            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, filename);

            if(!outputFile.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            }




        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();

        if (retry < 4){

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    retry++;
                    Log.d("download retrying.....", filename);
                    dowloadfile(ur, filename, installedApkList);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
```

How to solve this issue?
Please help

Comment: Do away with that strictmode and use threads for network code.

Comment: @blackapps when i remove strictmode, it generats error

Comment: Yes. And why dont you mention that error? And of course it does generate an error when you dont put your code in a thread. You didnt! Why? I told you to do so.

Comment: @blackapps i have removed that code, but main topic is to download apks and retry